# error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, ld

Can anybody tell me what's causing this error?

```
/tmp/ccHWwGhh.o: In function `main': A2.cpp:(.text+0x407): undefined reference to `binarysearch(std::string, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's my code:

```
//Located before main()
void binarysearch(string key, vector<string>& f2);

//Located in main()
binarysearch(key, file2);
//key is a string, file2 is a vector<string>

//Here is my code defining the function:
void binaraysearch(string key, vector<string> f2){
    sort_vector(f2);
    int mid = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = f2.size();
    bool found = false;
    while (left < right){
            mid = left + (left+right)/2;
            if (key > f2[mid]){
                    left = mid + 1;
            }
            else if(key < f2[mid]){
                    right = mid;
            }
            else{
                    found == true;
            }
    }
    if (found == true){
            cout << "YES: " << key << endl;
    }
    else{
            cout << " NO: " << key << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, in addition to that, there's a typo in the word `binary` in the function definition.

Answer (score 2):

A typo (or two):

```
//Located before main()
void binarysearch(string key, vector<string>& f2);

//Located in main()
binarysearch(key, file2);
//key is a string, file2 is a vector<string>

//Here is my code defining the function:
void binaraysearch(string key, vector<string> f2){
          ^
          here
```

One too many a's in the function definition.  There's also the discrepancy between a `vector<string>` and `vector<string>&` which won't help either.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of the function is as follows,

```
void binarysearch(string key, vector<string>& f2);
```

where as the in the function definition it has become,

```
void binaraysearch(string key, vector<string> f2){

}
```

This could be a type mismatch.